# Anaconda Spyder Error Installing - Acess Denied (Error 13)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to install Spyder ide from Anaconda Python, but the error 13 - acess denied to update the python, as listed below raises. Can anyone help me with it ?

C:>conda install -c anaconda spyder
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

added / updated specs:
    - spyder

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0         --> 2018.03.07-0         anaconda
certifi:         2018.4.16-py36_0     --> 2018.4.16-py36_0     anaconda
conda:           4.5.4-py36_0         --> 4.5.11-py36_0        anaconda
openssl:         1.0.2o-h8ea7d77_0    --> 1.0.2o-h8ea7d77_0    anaconda
qt:              5.9.5-vc14he4a7d60_0 --> 5.9.5-vc14he4a7d60_0 anaconda [vc14]
spyder:          3.2.8-py36_0         --> 3.2.8-py36_0         anaconda
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Acess denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Acess Denied')

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you're the only user in your computer, it's a bad idea to install Anaconda as admin because 1) Every time you need to install/update a package you need to do it as admin and not as a regular user; and 2) You could have some problems while running Spyder, Jupyter or other programs that need to write to disk your preferences, temporary files, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch the PowerShell/Cmd in admin mode.

Comment: I am in admin mode

Comment: sorry, actually I was logged as administrator but the shell was not, it works, thanks

Comment: This kind of problem is permissions problem, try to run it trough CMD admin mode or PowerShell admin mode ( Windows key + x, A) or see if the folder have the right permissions.